# How do I set a gradient on a marker in a Microsoft Chart Controls Bubble chart?

Tags: microsoft-chart-controls

When using 3D graphs the markers have a nice gradient 3D effect.

[image]

Is it possible to get that effect on a marker on a 2D chart?

Comment: Did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3D graph with the point depth set to 0.

```
 area.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
 area.Area3DStyle.PointDepth = 0;
```